# Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers on Solus

Tags: driver, broadcom, solus

all.  I've been having trouble installing broadcom drivers that actually work for my PCIe WiFI card.  Specifically, I want to know specifically the consecutive steps one must take to install the proper Broadcom drivers for this card: Rosewill RNX-AC1900PCE.  I found this page referring to it:

https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Rosewill_RNX-AC1900PCE

- it appears to me model BCM4360 (which seems to be important referring to this post:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Okay.  It's Rosewill product support page only has Windows drivers available (if you do not believe me, check it out).  I saw this post

https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5a35zn/wifi_not_working_broadcom_bc4360/

referring to the same Broadcom chip, but with worrisome news (it was hard to get working, and it worked less effectively than it did on Windows).

I've posted about this question asking for help/developer support in the Solus Discus forum: https://discuss.getsol.us/d/243-broadcom-drivers-not-working

And in the Solus Development Portal: https://dev.getsol.us/T7698

With no luck. I know for a fact it was working perfectly a few weeks ago on Solus.

I'm not really sure what to do.  Is there anyone on here smart enough to help me through my troubles?  Thanks!

EDIT: It somehow resolves itself after a DoFlicky installation of the driver and a reboot... even though this was the fourth time I tried this?  Oh well, the driver issues will always be mysterious to me.